# HttpClient redirecting

Tags: java, redirect, httpclient

I am trying to write a video downloader from kissanime.to . I am using HttpClient library. This site is using cloudflare. It redirects after 5 secs. How can I set so my application will go to the redirected link? My code below isnt working. Where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String entityContents = EntityUtils.toString(entity);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that given site is under DDOS protection mode (maybe you try to open it too often?) to workaround you would need to stop hitting it that much (e.g. wait some time between tries). Or if you insist use some javascript executing library (Rhino?) that would execute javascript that cloudflare is using.

Comment: I'v tried with breaks, still aint working. I'v setup the user.agent but it isn't working as well. The weird thing is that I can acces the page via chrome without problem. I will read about Rhino, thanks ;)